# Visual studio conflicts between Reference and Platform

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

Since I upgraded my target framework to 4.6.1 for a C# ASP.Net project I get a lot of conflict warnings during build. 50+ Messages like:

> Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "0.0.0.0" [] to Version "4.0.2.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.

They are all related to .NET System library. I could of course remap all references but somehow I think that is not the proper solution. If I rebuild with output 'detailed', I get more information:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.ConflictResolution.targets(33,5): message NETSDK1041: Encountered conflict between 'Reference:System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL' and 'Reference:System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation'.  NETSDK1033: Choosing 'Reference:System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation' because AssemblyVersion '4.0.2.0' is greater than '4.0.1.0'.

Somehow there seems to be a version conflict between a .NET framework in the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1 and C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib.

I don't know how to make sure it uses references from the same place. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you re-install all NuGet packages (`Update-Package -Reinstall` in the Nuget command window) and then double-click assembly binding warnings if one suggests to add binding redirects (it will open a dialog that will ask for your permission to automatically edit the web.config)?

Comment: I did and did not get any assembly binding warning :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Visual studio conflicts between Reference and Platform

It seems because that:

> This is due to the **injected support for NETStandard 2.0. We inject new
>   assemblies into NET 4.6.1 and later desktop projects in order to add
>   support for netstandard2.0**. We do this in targets now instead of
>   packages because its no longer a requirement to reference a package to
>   build a netstandard library. This injection happens whenever we see a
>   netstandard1.5 or greater library referenced (see dotnet/sdk#1386).

To resolve this issue, you could add binding redirect to those reference.

Check [System.Net.Http v4.2.0.0 being copied/loaded from MSBuild tooling](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25773) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wish I'd knew what a "binding redirect" is. I've followed the thread you pointed to and I didn't understand a thing. However, I've got this same problem just from creating an ASP.Net Core Angular project with "dotnet new angular -o my-new-app" as instructed by MS in the docs ("Use the Angular project template with ASP.NET Core") BEFORE installing Net Core 2.2 SDK and targeting to it afterwards. Creating a new project with the SDK correctly installed made things work correctly.

Comment: I have encountered the same issue in a group of projects that revolve around class libraries that contain code that dates from 2009 onwards, targets NET Framework 4.5 and below (down to 3.5), and the solution makes no reference whatsoever to ASP components. Thankfully, the messages are warnings, but even those bug me.

Comment: But how can you do that for an Azure Function? v1 functions don't allow binding redirects

Answer (score 0):

One of my co-worker the upgrade the .Net version to 4.6.1 .
After updating my git locally, I got the same issue. 
I got "Consider app.config remapping of assembly" for many .dll

I first wanted to update my 4.6.1 framework but I got this message :
".NET Framework 4.6.1 ou une mise à jour ultérieure est déjà installé sur cet ordinateur."

After reading the related link :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/troubleshoot-blocked-installations-and-uninstallations

It seems that there is a "link" between on sdk and the previous ones.

I install then the most recent version of the .NET SDK (4.8) : ndp48-devpack-enu.exe.

After the end of installation I rebuild my project and it is working

+

Answer (score 0):

Setting NUGET_PACKAGES variable did not solve my problem. Also, I noticed that the nuget packages are available in 'SYSWOW64' based path but MSBUID via Jenkins running in system service account is looking at 'System32' path.